# Multiline string to Spark Dataframe no break

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a multiline string I would like to convert into a df.

```
val string= 
"""
Here is the

multiline/multi paragraph

example.
"""
```

I'm looking for a df that looks like:

```
+--------------------+---+
|               value|doc|
+--------------------+---+
|Here is the         |  1|
|multiline/multipar..|   |
|example.            |   |
+--------------------+---+
```

What I am getting is:

```
+--------------------+---+
|               value|doc|
+--------------------+---+
|Here is the         |  1|
|multiline/multipar..|  2|
|example.            |  3|
+--------------------+---+
```

Here's my code:

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiLine", "true").text("test1.txt")
val df_id = df.withColumn("doc",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
df_id.show()
```

Comment: Is it a multi-line String or a text file for which a record might be on multiple lines ?

Comment: It's a multiline string. I tried Seq((1, string))toDF(colname1, colname2) at first. Since that didn't work, I was trying out writing the string into a text file and using read.textFile.

Comment: for spark 2.4+, use lineSep, for example `\n\n` for paragraph mode `val df = spark.read.option("lineSep", "\n\n").text("test1.txt")`.  or any substring/char which wont show in the text to get all texts into one row.

Comment: or `option("wholetext", "true")` to read all texts into one record

Comment: ("wholetext", "true") worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jxc was able to help me in the comments above, I'm only rewriting their solution here since there's no option for me to show their comments as accepted solution.

```
val df = spark.read.option("wholetext", "true").text("test1.txt")
val df_id = df.withColumn("doc",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
df_id.show()
```

and

```
val input = sc.wholeTextFiles("test1.txt").toDF("text", "doc")
```

both worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote the input string and you should be using `csv` reader as the `text` method of DataFrameReader has no option `multiLine`:

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiLine", "true")
              .option("quote", "\"")
              .option("escape", "\"")
              .csv("test1.txt")
```

You can find [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv-java.lang.String...-) the options available for each method.